# No way to make any changes on com_content category blog view - T3 Template

Tags: joomla-2.5, overrides, com-content, t3-framework

I am out of ideas with this one... I have to make a few changes on the category blog template on a Joomla 2.5 site. The issue is that whatever I do in any of the templates of the view, it won't be displayed on the front-end.

I have checked everything I can think of...

Caches, template overrides, other system plugins that could cache/server cached content, expire headers ...

I instruct the template files to die and they don't... The latest point my changes can have effect is at the view.html.php file. 
After that point nothing.

It's over an hour that I am messing with this and have no clue yet...

Does anyone have any good idea of what else I could check ?

It's a T3 framework template.

Comment: When you say caches, did you clear the Joomla cache **and** the cache that comes with your template framework?

Comment: yep - joomla, template, browser, disable system cache plugin - visited in incognito mode - anything that I could think around cache I did. Also checked with an online tool, if the wesbite serves cached content and it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay - here it is. 
This site uses outdated Joomla and outdated T3v3 framework. T3v3 holds its overrides inside the T3 system plugin. I had long time to use a T3 template and I didn't see this right away.

Full path:

> plugins/system/jat3v3/t3v3base/html/

But, even this way, I would expect that any custom override inside the template should take precedence over the overrides inside the plugin. But this wasn't the case.
I searched a little and found a post in JA forums about this issue. That was a bug of the T3 framework, which probably shall be fixed in the current version.

Reference to the JA forum:
[**Overriding T3V3 core Joomla component/module templates**](http://www.joomlart.com/forums/showthread.php?82329-Overriding-T3V3-core-Joomla-component-module-templates)

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this type of problem with framework based templates (gantry, T3, warp, etc ..).

For example, you can modify:

> /plugins/system/t3/base-bs3/html/com_content/category/blog.php

or any of the files in :

> /plugins/system/t3/base-bs3/html/com_content/category

Main drawback : be careful when you update T3 framework plugin.

Comment: yes it's T3 - and did you find what's behind that ?